# How to create Sub Item on Xml Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-xml, asp.net-3.5

In northwind database .I use **order and orderDetails** table.I want to create a xml file ,where **order** show on Item tag on XML and **orderdetails** show on **sub item**.Suppose orderid=1 show on Item tag then **orderdetais**table information of **OrderID=1**
show on sub-Item.

```
 XElement xml = new XElement("MyMenu",
                      from c in db.Orders
                      //where (c.ParentID == 0)
                      orderby c.OrderID
                      select new XElement("Item",
                                c.OrderID == null ? null : new XAttribute("OrderID", c.OrderID),
                                 c.ShipName == null ? null : new XAttribute("ShipName", c.ShipName),
                                  c.OrderDate == null ? null : new XAttribute("OrderDate", c.OrderDate)


                                )
                      );

            xml.Save(@"C:\contacts.xml");
```

What should i need to add on my above syntax.Show me syntax.Thanks in advance.I work on C#.Above syntax show the bellow output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyMenu>
  <Item OrderID="10248" ShipName="Vins et alcools Chevalier" OrderDate="1996-07-04T00:00:00" />
  <Item OrderID="10249" ShipName="Toms Spezialitäten" OrderDate="1996-07-05T00:00:00" />
  <Item OrderID="10250" ShipName="Hanari Carnes" OrderDate="1996-07-08T00:00:00" />
</MyMenu>
```

**I want bellow out put**

```
    <MyMenu>
      <Item OrderID="10248" ShipName="Vins et alcools Chevalier" OrderDate="1996-07-04T00:00:00" >
      <SubItem>  
       ..........
       ..........Contain detailTable Information for OrderID="10248"
       ...........
    </SubItem>
</Item>      
    </MyMenu>
```

**My bellow syntax fail to create above output:**

```
 XElement xml = new XElement("MyMenu",
                      //from c in db.Orders
                       from c in db.Orders
                       join od in db.Order_Details on c.OrderID equals od.OrderID
                      //where (c.ParentID == 0)
                      orderby c.OrderID
                      select new XElement("Item",
                                c.OrderID == null ? null : new XAttribute("OrderID", c.OrderID),
                                 c.ShipName == null ? null : new XAttribute("ShipName", c.ShipName),
                                  c.OrderDate == null ? null : new XAttribute("OrderDate", c.OrderDate),
                          new XElement("SubItem",
                               od.OrderID == null ? null : new XAttribute("OrderID", od.OrderID),
                               od.ProductID == null ? null : new XAttribute("ProductID", od.ProductID),
                               od.Quantity == null ? null : new XAttribute("Quantity", od.Quantity)
                               )


                                )
                      );
```

**Above syntax create bellow output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyMenu>
  <Item OrderID="10250" ShipName="Hanari Carnes" OrderDate="1996-07-08T00:00:00">
    <SubItem OrderID="10250" ProductID="41" Quantity="10" />
  </Item>
  <Item OrderID="10250" ShipName="Hanari Carnes" OrderDate="1996-07-08T00:00:00">
    <SubItem OrderID="10250" ProductID="51" Quantity="35" />
  </Item>
  <Item OrderID="10250" ShipName="Hanari Carnes" OrderDate="1996-07-08T00:00:00">
    <SubItem OrderID="10250" ProductID="65" Quantity="15" />
  </Item>
</MyMenu>
```

**How to put OrderID="10250" all subItem under one Item tag?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XElement xml = new XElement("MyMenu",
    //from c in db.Orders
    from c in db.Orders
    orderby c.OrderID
    select new XElement("Item",
        c.OrderID == null ? null : new XAttribute("OrderID", c.OrderID),
        c.ShipName == null ? null : new XAttribute("ShipName", c.ShipName),
        c.OrderDate == null ? null : new XAttribute("OrderDate", c.OrderDate),
        from od in db.Order_Details
        where od.OrderID == c.OrderID
        select new XElement("SubItem", 
            od.OrderID == null ? null : new XAttribute("OrderID", od.OrderID),
            od.ProductID == null ? null : new XAttribute("ProductID", od.ProductID),
            od.Quantity == null ? null : new XAttribute("Quantity", od.Quantity)
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

[LINQ to XML : Creating complex XML through LINQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20150824174026/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/wriju/archive/2008/02/18/linq-to-xml-creating-complex-xml-through-linq.aspx)